# promoted properties don't show in send port filters

Tags: biztalk

**The problem:**

Promoted properties can't be found in the property combo box in the filters tab of a send port. The properties show in the schema as being promoted.

**Environment:**

I'm using biztalk 2010

Comment: How did you promote the properties?

Comment: I think the problem is they should have been distinguished fields instead of properties.

Comment: No, that's not the problem. Distinguished fields cannnot be used for routing, i.e. they can't be used to build a filter. Silly question, but I've got to ask: have you restarted your host instances after deploying the assembly with the schemas?

Comment: I did a full stop on the application and restarted several times. I did add some distinguished fields which seemed to solve the problem. It might have been coincidental and recompiling fixed it. Thanks for the help all!

Answer (score 4):

Is the schema and property schema in the same BizTalk application as the send port? If not you need to reference the application that contains the schema to get the property in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

1. Make Sure the application that you deploy does have the refrence for the Schema's.
2. Stop the applicatuion in the Admin Console with Fll Termination Option.
3. Referesh the application in the Admin console and restart.

This should surly help you.